# Collision detection with Godot 4.0 3D

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am a newbe to programing in GDScript 2.0 and am new to GD in general.
I need to set the player position to `0,0,0` when touching an object that is in the group called "lava".

I am using godot 4.0 and trying to make a 3d game.

Code:

```
func _body_entered(body):
    if is_in_group("lava"):
        character_body.translation = Vector3(1, 1, 1)
        # Set the position of the node to (x, y, z)`[enter image description here][1]
```

It is not giving me an error but it is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just do this

```
for index in range(get_slide_collision_count()):
    var collision = get_slide_collision(index)
    if collision.get_collider().is_in_group("Lava"):
        print("colided")
```

Comment: Please be more specific on commenting how the code in the answer solves the problem

Comment: This is not helpful. It's just a block of code with no context. We can't read you mind and automatically know where this fits into

Answer (score 0):

Making a method called `_body_entered` is not sufficient. Make sure you connected the `"body_entered"` signal to your method.

You can do this form the editor, by selecting the `Area3D` or `RidigBody3D` you are using, going to the "Node" panel (by default docked on the right), and then double clicking the signal. Godot will ask you to which `Node` and which method to connect it to.

See [connecting-a-signal-in-the-editor](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html#connecting-a-signal-in-the-editor).

---

**Addendum**:

If the object is not an `Area3D` or a `RigidBody3D` (e.g. the object is a `StaticBody3D`) then it does not have a `"body_entered"` that you can use.

In the case of a `StaticBody3D` that does not move※, then detecting the collision in the `CharacterBody3D` (as [OP answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75845688/402022) suggests) is sufficient, because the collision would be a result of the motion of the `CharacterBody3D` and not the other way around.

※: The recommended way to make a moving platform in Godot 4 is with an `AnimatableBody3D` which are `StaticBody3D`.

Otherwise, I would suggest to change the `StaticBody3D` to an `Area3D`. I have outlined some alternative approaches to get `"body_entered"` in an `StaticBody3D` [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/204775/10408).